# Uppercase first letter of variable value javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, innerhtml

I am attempting to uppercase the output string of a variable value as follows;

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById('namePlaceholder').innerHTML =  name.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + ' is here ';
```

name.value is a user input so my attempt is to uppercase the first letter of name.
example

```
name.value = james
```

preferred outcome James is here.

is there a simple javascript solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mutate strings directly as you are trying - you have to create a new string by concatenating the pieces you want:

```
document.getElementById('namePlaceholder').innerHTML =  
  name.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +   // will give you "J"
  name.value.slice(1).toLowerCase() +    // will give you "ames"
  ' is here ';
```

In lay terms, the `slice(1)` part says "grab everything after the first character". In more technical terms, if you have the name James, you can think of it as a series of letters (not an array, but kinda):

`['J', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's']`.

You can access individual letters like `name[0]`, which will give you "J" and `name[3]` which will give you "e". You can then do `name.slice(1)`, which will start at "a" and grab everything after it: "ames". To illustrate further, you could do `name.slice(-2)` to get the last 2 characters: "es". Or, if you want "me", you can do `name.slice(2, 4)`.

Comment: Have added 1 line as follows: name.value = name.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +   // will give you "J"
  name.value.slice(1).toLowerCase() +  (so I dont have to do it for each if statement.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `substring`

```
document.getElementById('namePlaceholder').innerHTML =  
        name.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
        name.value.substr(1) +
        ' is here ';
```

Using `Regular Expression:`

```
document.getElementById('namePlaceholder').innerHTML =  
     name.value.replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase()); + ' is here ';
```

exactly similar to the following:

```
document.getElementById('namePlaceholder').innerHTML =  
     name.value.replace(/^\w/, function (chr) {
        return chr.toUpperCase();
     }); 
     + ' is here ';
```